# Detect identical torrent files

Tags: python, bittorrent

I manage to decode a torrent file successfully using python and have the component parts of the torrent file nicely laid out as a dictionary.

What I want to detect next is if 2 torrent files are for the same set of files, so if is the case, to just extract the trackers from the second one.

The only idea that comes to my mind now, is to make a hash of the pieces part of torrent and see if the hash is the same for the 2.

I'm new with the torrent protocol, programming wise, so be gentile :).

Any body has any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I just found the answer in another question, please correct me if I'm wrong. If I make a hash of the whole info of the torrent, the hashes are the same:

```
torrent1 = decode(open("test1.torrent", "rb").read())
torrent2 = decode(open("test2.torrent", "rb").read())

m = hashlib.sha1()
m.update(str(torrent1["info"]))
print m.hexdigest()

m = hashlib.sha1()
m.update(str(torrent2["info"]))
print m.hexdigest()
```

Comment: It looks like you are only hashing info. I would hash the whole torrent, no?

Comment: No. The torrent file may contain different trackers info and this is exactly what I want to do: if they are for the same set of files, extract the trackers from both of them

Comment: you don't even have to hash it if you're just comparing. You could just compare the info-dicts.

Comment: OP asked for equality being defined as having "the same set of files", so the answer is wrong. If you indeed want the total info dict counted, the obvious way is to calculate the info hashes (i.e. use a package that does) and compare those.

Comment: @pyroscope: And isn't this what I did: a hash of the info?

Comment: You need to use a bencode/bedecode library to decode the torrent file first. The solution you gave wouldn't work without decoding the torrent file.